# Enforce constraint name uniqueness

Tags: postgresql

I just noticed that PostgreSQL allows repeating foreign key (and possibly other constraint) names across the database as long as they are on a different table.

So if the parent table is `Foo` and it has two child tables `BarX` and `BarY`, the foreign keys on both tables can be named `FK_fooid`.

This, IMO, is a terrible design because

```
select * from information_schema.referential_constraints
where constraint_name = 'FK_fooid'
```

will return two *identical* rows with no ability to differentiate which one corresponds to which table/key.

Is there a way to disable repetition of constraint names across a database in Postgres and to enforce that each constraint has a unique name?

Comment: This (and the reply) sums it up: https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/pan.2004.09.05.22.56.56.521040@arvin.dk

Comment: is he saying there is no solution ?

Comment: Which version are you on?  Since 8.0 the automatically created constraint name should be different inside a schema - on my box they look like `{tablename}_{columname}_fkey`.  See also the note at https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/information-schema.html

Comment: @dezso - `9.0.13` but I think the DBA actually assigned poorly chosen names (duplicates)

Comment: I see.  In any case, tell your DBA to upgrade to a supported version (9.1+ currently).  If it is impossible for some reason, upgrade to the latest minor version of 9.0 (9.0.23).

Comment: is the 9.0 no longer supported ?

Comment: basically, what does it mean that our version is past EOL considering that the software is free and we don't get support?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *will return two IDENTICAL rows with no ability to differentiate which one corresponds to which table/key.*

Then don't use `information_schema`:

```
select nsp.nspname as constraint_schema,
       c.conname as constraint_name,  
       format('%I.%I', ts.nspname, t.relname) as target_table,
       pg_get_constraintdef(c.oid) as constraint_definition
from pg_class t 
  join pg_constraint c on t.oid = c.conrelid   
  join pg_namespace nsp on t.relnamespace = nsp.oid 
  join pg_namespace ts on t.relnamespace = ts.oid
where c.contype in ('f') 
 and c.conname = 'fk_fooid';
```

Example: http://rextester.com/DAR30737